# Calculator with stack in C Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, stack

I want to make a calculator which can calculate with logical operators. I create two stacks, one of them is for 1s and 0s and the other is for operators. I can compile as well but when I want to try it, says: "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". Thank you in advance

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <Stack.h>

#define MAX_EXPR_SIZE 100

int Evaluate01(char *expr) {
    int final, i = 0;

    Stack *stack1 = (Stack *)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    Stack *stack2 = (Stack *)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    if(!stack1 || !stack2) {
       //print error and return
    }

    Stack_initialize(stack1);
    Stack_initialize(stack2);


    do {

        if (expr[i] == '0' || expr[i] == '1'){
            int foo3 = expr[i] - '0';
            Stack_Push(stack1, foo3);
        }

        else if (expr[i] == 0x96){
            int foo3 = Stack_Pop(stack1);
            int sum = !foo3;
            Stack_Push(stack1, sum);
        }

        else if (expr[i] == 0x62 ||
                 expr[i] == 0x46 ||
                 expr[i] == 0x43 ||
                 expr[i] == 'x'){

            Stack_Push(stack2, expr[i]);
        }   

        else if (expr[i] == 0x41){
            int sum;
            int foo1= Stack_Pop(stack1);
            int foo2 = Stack_Pop(stack1);
            char op = Stack_Pop(stack2);

            switch(op){
                case 0x62:
                    sum = !foo1 || foo2;
                    Stack_Push(stack1, sum);
                    break;

                case 0x46:
                    sum = foo1 && foo2;
                    Stack_Push(stack1, sum);
                    break;

                case 0x43:
                    sum = foo1 || foo2;
                    Stack_Push(stack1, sum);
                    break;

                case 'x':
                    sum = foo1 ^ foo2;
                    Stack_Push(stack1, sum);
                    break;
            }
        }

        i++;
    }while (expr[i] != '\0');
     final = Stack_Pop(stack1);
     free(stack1);
     free(stack2);
     return final;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char expr[MAX_EXPR_SIZE+1];

    while(1) {

        printf("logical expression : ");
        scanf(" %s", expr);

        printf("results: ");
        printf("%d\n", Evaluate01(expr));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Edit**: Now it's working. Thank you so much!

Comment: Your while statement seems to be true forever. I can't find a line changing the value of expr.

Comment: `Evaluate01` does not return a value

Comment: This `}while (expr != NULL);` probably needs to be `}while (expr[i] != 0 );`. And you need to check `expr` contains at least one char if you are going to use a do-while loop.

Comment: `while (expr[i] !=0 );` doesn't work unfortunately and I have no idea how to end the while statement.

Comment: What line causes the segmentation fault? Have you run this with GDB or Valgrind/Dr Memory to test?

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`) & [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all when you're using comparison between characters and their ascii values you should use hexa base. For example:

```
expr[i] == 62
```

should be written as:

```
expr[i] == 0x62
```

Second you should use atoi when you convert character to int.

Furthermore you should first check that the allocation succeeded.
And in the end, the while iteration should loop while expr[i] != NULL.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <Stack.h>

#define MAX_EXPR_SIZE 100

int Evaluate01(char *expr) {
    int i = 0;
    Stack *stack1 = (Stack *)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    Stack *stack2 = (Stack *)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    if(!stack1 || !stack2) {
       //print error and return
    }

    Stack_initialize(stack1);
    Stack_initialize(stack2);


    do {

        if (expr[i] == '0' || expr[i] == '1'){
            int foo3 = atoi(expr[i] - '0');
            Stack_Push(stack1, foo3);
        }

        else if (expr[i] == 0x96){
            int foo3 = Stack_Pop(stack1);
            int sum = !foo3;
            Stack_Push(stack1, sum);
        }

        else if (expr[i] == 0x62 ||
                 expr[i] == 0x46 ||
                 expr[i] == 0x43 ||
                 expr[i] == 0x120){

            Stack_Push(stack2, expr[i]);
        }   

        else if (expr[i] == 0x41){
            int sum;
            int foo1= Stack_Pop(stack1);
            int foo2 = Stack_Pop(stack1);
            char op = Stack_Pop(stack2);

            switch(op){
                case 0x62:
                    sum = !foo1 || foo2;
                    Stack_Push(stack1, sum);
                    break;

                case 0x46:
                    sum = foo1 && foo2;
                    Stack_Push(stack1, sum);
                    break;

                case 0x43:
                    sum = foo1 || foo2;
                    Stack_Push(stack1, sum);
                    break;

                case 0x120:
                    sum = foo1 ^ foo2;
                    Stack_Push(stack1, sum);
                    break;
            }
        }

        i++;
    }while (expr[i] != NULL);

    free(stack1);
    free(stack2);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char expr[MAX_EXPR_SIZE+1];

    while(1) {

        printf("logical expression : ");
        scanf(" %s", expr);

        printf("results: ");
        printf("%d\n", Evaluate01(expr));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't atoi take a string as the argument? how would this work `int foo3 = atoi(expr[i] - '0');`?

Comment: My bad, you should convert it to string. 
char str[2];
str[0] = expr[i] - '0';
str[1] = "\0";

Comment: If you're just trying to translate a char to its integer representation, I don't see why you'd need atoi at all. Also, `str[0] = expr[i] - '0';` should be `str[0] = expr[i];` if you're going to use atoi.

Comment: `bool01.c:72:21: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
     }while (expr[i] != NULL);
` Can't finalize the statement

Comment: @Rufus try:
while(expr[i] != "\0")

Comment: @BobbySacamano basically you are right, the thing is the atoi and strtol are more secure ways to accomplish the conversion.

Comment: @C.MerabiShmulik `bool01.c:64:17: warning: case label value exceeds maximum value for type
                 case 0x120:
                 ^
bool01.c:72:21: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
     }while (expr[i] != "\0");
` I didn't get the first problem actually

Comment: first of all `while(expr[i] != "\0")` should be `while(expr[i] != '\0')`. `"\0"` is a string literal in C, which is still a pointer type. Also, why would atoi and strtol be more secure than just a switch statement with all the numeric representations of chars? String functions have a possibility of buffer overflow, which makes them fairly dangerous.

Comment: @rufus `0x100 - 1` is the maximum value of unsigned char. 0x120 exceeds that.

Comment: @Rufus I'm pretty sure you just shouldn't have added the `0x` in front of the numbers. Is there any particular reason you're using the numeric value, instead of character literals? The character literals are there for portability.

Comment: @BobbySacamano this is my assingment. I could not use `'` sign with `case` and I have to use it. So the solution was ascii table. But now the program isn't working well. OR, XOR and NOT operators are not working.

Comment: @Rufus You can probably figure out why they aren't working if you step through it with GDB. It probably was caused by changing all of the decimal numbers to hexadecimal though.